# How to get POST data from request asp mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working with mvc5. I use widget that upload image to cloud and call event. On success I need to write some info to database. The data in the first line of code.

```
$(document).on('cloudinarywidgetsuccess', function (e, data /*this data I need in database*/) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Cabinet/UploadImageCallback",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                console.log("db error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("An error has occured!!!");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to get data in controller in json format. If I send in this way to .php, I can access data in this way `$_POST['KEY']`. How to get the similar functionality in MVC5?

Comment: how does `data` looks like ?

Comment: what structure ? Create a class with same structure and use that as your param. When the data is posted, Model binder will map the posted data to an object of that class and you can access that.

Comment: @Shyju Thanks, solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a model as a parameter; most of the time ASP.Net MVC's Default ModelBinder can map to your model.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "@Url.Action("UploadImageCallback", "Cabinet")", // If you want strongly-typed URL
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   method: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify(data)
   ...
});

public class CustomerModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImageCallback(CustomerModel model)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I have read about model binders. So if you need some fields you can just write the next in action: `public ActionResult UploadImageCallback(string field1, string field3)` . Model binder automatically searches for json variables with the same name as parameters of action in available data sources( POST, GET, SESSION - doesn't matter) . The same names is the first, the second binder tries to convert string value to the type of parameter, if both conditions are true, binder sends value to action.